# Increment value in twig file

Tags: twig

I have a loop withing a .twig file that outputs elements.

I need to increment a value withing each element. I know how to do it in PHP, but an not clear how to do it withing a twig document. I can't really do it in controller. Any suggestions?

```
{% set myVal = 50 %}

{% for item in items%}
     {{ myVal = myVal + 10 }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Use this:

```
{% set myVal = 50 %}

{% for item in items %}
     {% set myVal = myVal + 10 %}
{% endfor %}
```

For declaring, setting values, setting blocks/forms, etc. you must use `{% %}`. For output, there is `{{ }}`

Answer (score 27):

Here is the better way -

```
{% for item in items %}
  {% set counter = ( counter | default(0) ) + 1 %}
  <p>{{ counter ~ ' ). ' ~ item.title }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

See how the counter is being increased by 1.

Comment: Nice. It's not immediately clear, though, what you are doing here. But it's basically initializing and incrementing the counter variable in one line. The `default(0)` sets the value to 0 if counter is null (ie hasn't been set/initialized). Just thought I'd explain that incase someone else wonders...

Comment: How is it “better”? If find this code rather obscure, which is especially unwelcome considering Twig’s target users.